# Rake like dependency functionality in Elixir Mix tasks?

Tags: rake, elixir, elixir-mix

In Rake, one can specify dependencies between tasks. The engine then build a dependencies tree and perform those tasks by the order of dependencies and only once each task.

Is there a similar mechanism for that in elixir/mix ?

```
task seed_users: [:seed_companies] do 
  # actions
end

task :seed_companies do
  # actions
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any inbuilt functionality for this, but you can use [`Mix.Task.run/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Task.html#run/2) to achieve this:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.SeedUsers do
  def run(_args) do
    IO.puts "started seed_users"
    Mix.Task.run "seed_companies"
    Mix.Task.run "seed_companies"
    IO.puts "completed seed_users"
  end
end

defmodule Mix.Tasks.SeedCompanies do
  def run(_args) do
    IO.puts "started seed_companies"
    IO.puts "completed seed_companies"
  end
end
```

Example run:

```
$ mix seed_users
started seed_users
started seed_companies
completed seed_companies
completed seed_users
```

Note that `Mix.Task.run/2` does not run the task if it has already been run once, so if you call `Mix.Task.run/2` twice, as in the example above, it's only run once. If you'd like to run a task more than once, you need to call [`Mix.Task.reenable/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Task.html#reenable/1) after every run.

Comment: I think you are missing `use Mix.Task` in each module